# Error with URL generation for nested and shallow resources in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I'm running into a routing issue for nested resources on rails. In my routes.rb file I have:

```
     resources :users, shallow: true do
       resources :jobs
     end
```

When create a new job posting, I'm getting an error that reads Couldn't find Job with 'id'=3 [WHERE "job"."user_id" = ?] for the show view (after a job is posted, I want the posting user to see the job post).

I've noticed in my URL that there's a random dot for my nested routes. I'm not sure where it came from or how to get ride of it but I think it's causing the application to not recognize the params (i.e. for domain.com/jobs/3.80, I'm currently logged in as User #3 and this should be job #80).

Need some advice on how to troubleshoot. I'm developing on AWS if helpful.

Controller

```
    class JobsController < ApplicationController

      def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @job = @user.jobs.find(params[:id])
      end


      def index
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @jobs = @user.jobs.all
      end


      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @job = current_user.jobs.find(params[:id])
      end


      def new
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        if @user.approved_user
          @job = @user.jobs.build
        else
          flash[:danger] = "User not authorized to post a job."
          redirect_to root_url
        end
      end


      def create
        @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
        @job =         @user.jobs.create(user_job_params)
redirect_to job_path(@user, @job)
        flash[:info] = "Job submitted and pending approval!"
      end

      def update
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @job = @user.jobs.find(params[:id])
        if @job.update_attributes(user_job_params)
          flash[:success] = "Job information updated!"
  redirect_to job_path(@user, @job)
else 
  flash[:warning] = "No changes made to job information!"
render 'edit'
end
        end


        private

        def user_job_params
          params.require(:job).permit(:XXXXXXXX)                           
        end
      end
```

Job New View:

```
        <% provide(:title, ‘Post a new job!’) %>
        <% provide(:button_text, 'Submit A New Job’) %>


        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= form_for([@user, @job], url: user_jobs_path(@user, @job) do |ff| %>



          <h4>Job Information</h4>

            <%= ff.label :job_name %>
            <%= ff.text_field :job_name, placeholder: “Job Name", class: 'form-control' %>
          …
        …

            <%= ff.submit yield(:button_text), class: "btn btn-primary" %>


          <% end %>
```

Job Show View:

```
         <% provide(:title, "#{@job.job_name} Job Page") %>
         <% provide(:button_text, 'Save changes') %>
         <div class="row">
           <aside class="col-md-12">
             <section class="user_info">
               <h1>
                 <%= "Job Page for #{@job.job_name} Program" %>
                 </h1>
                 <br>
                 <br>
                 <%= "Job By #{@user.job_profile.organization}" %>
                 </h4>

              <%= link_to 'Edit Job details',  edit_job_path(@job) %>  
              <br>
              <br>
              <%= link_to 'See all of your jobs',  user_jobs_path(@user) %>

             </section>

           </aside>
         </div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant view and controller code to your question.

Comment: Are you creating `jobs` for `current_user` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `create` and `update` actions...

Change this...

```
redirect_to job_path(@user, @job)
```

To this...

```
redirect_to job_path(@job)  # or redirect_to @job
```

Notice that, since you are using shallow nesting, your routes are no longer expecting a user. To verify, run `$ rails routes | grep job` and inspect the route for `jobs#show`, which should look like `/jobs/:id(.:format)`